# Not able to run gcloud auth activate-service-account in Docker

Tags: docker, maven, dockerfile, google-cloud-sdk

I want to run `gcloud auth activate-service-account` command during docker build to make sure my application can access GCP secrets manager. My docker file contents are as following:-

```
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17 as maven_builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY up-user-service/pom.xml .
COPY up-user-service/src ./src
RUN mvn clean install
RUN mv target/*.jar target/application.jar


FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine as builder
COPY --from=maven_builder /app/target/*.jar up-user-service/target/application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar up-user-service/target/application.jar extract
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine

COPY --from=builder dependencies/ ./
RUN true
COPY --from=builder snapshot-dependencies/ ./
RUN true
COPY --from=builder spring-boot-loader/ ./
RUN true

FROM ubuntu:22.04

# Install prerequisites
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
curl
CMD /bin/bash

RUN curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz > /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/gcloud
RUN tar -C /usr/local/gcloud -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
RUN /usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account  --key-file=/home/sdesai/Uplight/code/up-ms-java/application_default_credentials.json

COPY --from=builder application/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

Even after installing google-cloud-sdk, I am getting following error:-

```
 => ERROR [stage-3 8/9] RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account  --key-file=/home/sdesai/Uplight/code/up-ms-java/application_default_credentials.json                            0.3s 
------                                                                                                                                                                                 
 > [stage-3 8/9] RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account  --key-file=/home/sdesai/Uplight/code/up-ms-java/application_default_credentials.json:                                       
#0 0.296 /bin/sh: 1: gcloud: not found                                                                                                                                                 
------                                                                                                                                                                                 
Dockerfile:40                                                                                                                                                                          
--------------------
  38 |     RUN tar -C /usr/local/gcloud -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
  39 |     RUN /usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
  40 | >>> RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account  --key-file=/home/sdesai/Uplight/code/up-ms-java/application_default_credentials.json
  41 |     
  42 |     COPY --from=builder application/ ./
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c gcloud auth activate-service-account  --key-file=/home/sdesai/Uplight/code/up-ms-java/application_default_credentials.json" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
```

Why is the docker container still not able to run gcloud command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gcloud` command was not found in the $PATH. To fix this issue, you can update the environment variable before executing the `gcloud` command.

```
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin"
RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account  --key-file=/home/sdesai/Uplight/code/up-ms-java/application_default_credentials.json
```

A better option would be to install Google Cloud SDK via the package manager. For more information, please check this https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb

Comment: I tried setting the environment variable but now getting an error that it is not able to find the credential json file. But the file is present on my machine at same path. Exact error:- No such file or directory. Any idea why this error might be coming?

Comment: I was able to run gcloud auth activate-service-account after copying the key file to docker container during docker build

Comment: Yes, your path to the file is from the host --key-file=/home/sdesai/Uplight/code/up-ms-java/ you need to use COPY credentials file to the docker image.